# Font sometimes too small on a Mac

Tags: display, fonts, display-resolution, mac

Hello I am a Mac user and recently I installed Ubuntu on a Mac. Mine has a Retina display, and for some particular instances, the font size is too small to read. I have changed the system's display ratio and font et cetera, but there are still some cases where the font is extremely small and unable to read. I wonder if that is because my screen resolution is high or anything else...
Some additional piece of information is that when I first installed Ubuntu, everything is very tiny and I have to set the display scale to 200%. To be more specific, the Ubuntu on my Virtual Machine has the max resolution of 1280 * 800 while my Ubuntu installed in another real partition is 2560 * 1600. Pictures are attached to show some settings and the problem followed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucvyB.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI7eZ.png)

Comment: Do not change the resolution, increase scale instead.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. I maintained the high resolution, and the system itself is OK. It's just that some other application programs that I download has this problem.